# How to connect xamarin.forms with sql server

Tags: c#, xamarin

I am creating an application with xamarin.forms and need it to connect to a sql server base that is in my served, how do I make this connection?

Comment: I also suggest [Xamarin's guide for calling RESTful services](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/). If you go with their example, you would want to create a new Web API project/solution in Visual Studio. Your Web API project/solution would talk directly with SQL Server and your mobile app would talk to the Web API site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option is to create a webservice layer due to security reasons. However, it is possible to connect SQL Server with a Xamarin.Forms app and I wrote about it here (just for fun): http://icebeamwp.blogspot.cz/2016/09/conectando-una-app-de-xamarin-con-sql.html (it's in Spanish, but you can use an online translator or just send me a message and I'll gladly help).

Not recommended for a production environment, as I said, I did it only for the sake of trying something new :)